# where to store .properties file for use in c++ dll

Tags: c++, windows, dll, location, properties-file

I created a .properties file that contains a few simple *key = value* pairs.
I tried it out from a sample c++ console application, using imported java classes, and I was able to access it, no problem.

Now, I am trying to use it in the same way, from a C++ dll, which is being called by another (unmanaged) c++ project.

For some reason, the file is not being accessed.

Maybe my file location is wrong. Where should I be storing it?

What else might be the issue?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are mentioning "DLL" i guess, that you are using MS Windows. Finding a file there from a DLL, and independently from the logged on user is a restricted item. The best way is to store the file in a path assembled from the environment variable `ALLUSERSPROFILE`. This is the only location that is equal to all users and where all users usually have write access. Your applications data should reside in a private subdirectory named like < MyCompany > or < MyApplicationsName >. Type

```
echo %ALLUSERSPROFILE%
```

on a windows command line prompt to find out the actual location on a machine.

Store your data in i.e.:

```
%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\MyApp\
```

Your dll can then query the location of  ALLUSERSPROFILE using getenv:

```
char *allUsersData = getenv("ALLUSERSPROFILE");
```